# Is `this` keyword optional when accessing members in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, this, member

I notice that if you have a private member in a class, you can access it in the class methods by just referring to it's name. You do not need to say `this.memberName`, just `memberName` works. So is the this keyword optional in the context of member access?

I do see it is useful when you want to clarify the scope - when you have 2 variables with the same name. Is there any other reason to use it when accessing members?

Comment: If the compiler doesn't complain I think it's six of one half a dozen of the other.

Comment: Yes, it's optional. In my opinion, over-use of "this" clutters up the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# When To Use "This" Keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843288/c-when-to-use-this-keyword)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use the "this" keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I be using \`this\` by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253871/should-i-be-using-this-by-default)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's optional. The only times you'd have to use it are when you have a local variable that hides a member variable, or you want to refer to an [indexed property (aka indexer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Comment: Or if you want to call an extension method.

Comment: That is true, but there won't be that many situations where you'd want to do that. If you have access to the class, why would you be defining extension methods on it? The only reason I can think of is maybe in a class that inherits from IEnumerable and you want to use one of the extension methods defined in Enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally use `this` in instance member access from within an instance members like an instance method or property because whenever an instance method is called   `this`   (referring to the current object) is automatically passed in as an invisible parameter.

You cannot use `this` from within static members to access instance member... like you cannot use `this.x` or `this.y` (or even simple x and y) from within a static method or property if x and y are instance members. This is because `this` is undefined in a static member call. The static member belongs to the whole class... it has no idea which instance `this` is referring to. And that is due to the fact that when you call a static method or property , the call is of the format `ClassName.MethodName();` So the static method does not know what object `this` will refer.

`this` is also not optional (it must be used) as the first  modifier  in the parameter list of an extension method. In fact `this` is what identifies a static method as an extension method. Here now  `this` identifies the first parameter as the instance on which the extension method is working.

```
    using System;



    class Class_name
    {


        static  string static_variable="static";

        string instance_variable="instance";


        static void Main()
        {

            Class_name object_name = new Class_name();

            Console.WriteLine("Printing out instance and static variables from within Main() body :");

            Console.WriteLine(object_name.instance_variable);
            Console.WriteLine(Class_name.static_variable);

            /* Note that we cannot say either of the following :

                    object_name.static_variable 
                    Class_name.instance_variable


            */

            Console.WriteLine();




            // now lets call the static and instance methods

            object_name.Instance_method(); // Now this is the key call which 
            // passes "this" as an invisible parameter 
            // to the Instance_method. "this" refers to  
            //  object_name


            Class_name.Static_method();//  "this" is NOT passed to Static_method() because now 
            // the call is made on Class_name ... so there is nothing
            // to be represented by "this"


            Console.ReadLine();

        }



        void Instance_method()
        { 

            // here we receive "this" as an invisible parameter referring 
            // to the object on which  Instance_method is called (i.e. object_name)...
            // ... see the Main() method for comments at the call site. 


            Console.Write("Instace method called ... " +
                            "prints out instance variable twice, with and without 'this': ");

            // the following two calls mean exactly the same.

            Console.Write(this.instance_variable);
            Console.WriteLine (instance_variable);



            // one little additional point is that static members are 
            // accessible from within instance members


            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("static variables can also be accessed from within Instance_method: ");
            Console.WriteLine(static_variable);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();




        }


        static void Static_method()
        {

            // See the Main() method body for the call Class_name.Static_method()
            // Notice that this method is called on Class_name and not object_name
            // which means that there is no invisibly passed-in "this" parameter available
            // in this method. 

            // we can also not access the instance_variable in this method 
            // as instance variables are always part of some object. This method
            // is not called on any object, its called on Class_name.

            // Console.WriteLine(instance_variable); // Compiler error

            Console.WriteLine("Static method called ... prints out static variable: ");
            Console.WriteLine(static_variable);




        }






    }
```

Comment: I hope the added code will clarify the concept and remove confusion.  The code is specifically designed to illustrate the difference between accessing instance and static members from within instance and static members and also the flow of "this".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'this' is implied.  It can sometimes help for clarity.  And it is also necessary for calling methods and need to reference the current class.

Comment: You are wrong. I don't have to type "this." to call a method from "this" class.

Comment: I meant, if you want to call a method that reference back to calling class's members (i.e. "reference the current class").  Not just to call it.

Answer (score 0):

"This" is almost always optional when you call members of current class.

However, it is used for other purposes, e.g. to pass the current class instance as a parameter or to set a property,field or variable to the current instance.

The only case where you must use it to call a method is when you call an extension method:

```
class AClass {
    void CallIt() {
        Test();                     //not valid
        this.Test();                //valid 
    }
}
static class AnExtension {
    public static void Test(this AClass source) {

    }
}
```