# Should I follow the StyleCop rules for the C# codes I write in Razor syntax?

Tags: razor, stylecop

Especially about the "SA1126: PrefixCallsCorrectly" rule which tells us to use "this." prefix for instance members.

Should I follow these rules in the Razor syntax?

Example:

```
<span>Name: @this.Model.Name</span>
```

Or:

```
<span>@this.Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</span>
```

You may notice that the "this." is ineffective here (I'm agree). I want to follow a rule which is applicable for all my everyday codes.

And doesn't StyleCop check the Razor files?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the usage of the "this" prefix is kind of a personal (which can be argumented) choice.

You can find an interesting discussion on this point here
[Why does StyleCop recommend prefixing method or property calls with "this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562540/why-does-stylecop-recommend-prefixing-method-or-property-calls-with-this)

By the way, Resharper, for example, has the inverse rule by default (remove "useless" this - meaning useless for the compiler).

But frankly, in a View, I think it's more noise than help.

Other point : use HtmlHelpers like `@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Name)` in your case, as they're strongly typed, linked to model, take care of null values, etc.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I've add another example I forgot.

Comment: this can be usefull if you can have a confusion. Here, it's only noise (at my eyes) => still no

Answer (score 1):

> Should I follow these rules in the Razor syntax?

If you have decided that it's worthwhile adding the "this" in your .cs files, why wouldn't you want to apply it to C# code elsewhere, such as embedded in a Razor view file?  What if you were to have multiple lines of C# code in a `@{ }` block?  Would the "this" start to seem more useful?  (The issue of whether "this" is generally worthwhile is not particularly relevant here since you have presumably already standardized on using it.)

> And doesn't StyleCop check the Razor files?

Nope, StyleCop does not check Razor files.  The only parser currently included with StyleCop is a C# parser, which only examines files with a ".cs" extension.

Comment: We are not sure it's worthwhile adding the "this." in our CS files yet. We are struck between choosing "this." or "underscore" prefixes. I used the "this." prefix for about a year but now I'm confused: what is the benefit of distinguishing instance and static members? Just recognizing the fields from parameters and local variables are enough that can be happened with a "underscore" prefix. As you know we like a standard which is applicable on all our C# codes even about the Razor. If it cause noise as Nicole said (I’m agree) so it seems better to remove the “this.” prefix rule at all.